# How to find nearest City of out of a selected set

Tags: java, google-maps, postgis, openstreetmap

I need to get the nearest city out of a selected set of cities.

Our company has a list of subsidiaries (some 100 in my country). We get around 3000 requests a day. This requests should be assigned to the subsidiaries (by geographical distance).

Is there an API to do this?

The best would be a (java) GoogleMaps API or similar webservice.

Best Regards,
Christian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I would do is to construct a [Voronoi diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram#Illustration) of your subsidiaries, based on geographical distance and store that diagram in the form that can be used in your code. Then, look for the containing cell for each request and that will tell you which subsidiary is the closest one.

If you really want to make it precise, you could use OSM's road network to construct the diagram based on the driving distance, not simply geographical one.

Answer (score 0):

Get the coordinates from [Nominatim](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), it should be straight forward to make requests from a java application. 
Calculate the great circle distance for every city to every city. I have to admit that the result might by an 300 by 300? array. However it may contain only integer. Hold it in memory for future requests.
Find the entry with the lowest number in the row or column.

Answer (score 0):

Bit of an old question and maybe too late an answer for you.

A good approximation for speed concerns where absolute precision is not of the essence is to draw a rectangle around a point (the one you need to find the closest subsidiaries here). That rectangle would natively have NE and SW coordinate boundaries (or NW/SE).

To find the closest subsidiaries, ones need to find all of which the NE coordinate is "less" than that of the rectangle and "more" than that of the SW boundary.

I am quoting "more" and "less" because they might mean differently based of where on earth you are.

I wrote https://github.com/grumlimited/geocalc for my own need a few years back. Take a look at the section about names "BoundingArea".